# NLTK in pydev eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, nltk

I have python 2.6 , NLTK for python , and a couple of external resources which I am using. Problem is, everything is recognised (import statements)

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize 
import re 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files\eclipse\Martin Project Folder\labs2\src\lab2.py", line 22, in <module>
    sents.append(sent_tokenize( review.raw( ) ))

on line 22 you :

Resource 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: >>>
  nltk.download().
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\Martinos/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\Python26\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\Python26\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Martinos\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

---

Anyone know why is that since the program should find the punkd version IN the nltk (since it recognises nltk) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message in stacktrace said you should invoke a function 'nltk.download()' from  python console to download resources you need. Also this message lists all paths in which nltk tried to find the missing resource.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the nltk resources. To resolve the issue do as following:

```
Python mode in the Terminal and run following commands 
import nltk 
nltk.download()
```