# Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load

Tags: python, jenkins, nltk

When trying to load the `punkt` tokenizer...

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

...a `LookupError` was raised:

```
> LookupError: 
>     *********************************************************************   
> Resource 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: nltk.download().   Searched in:
>         - 'C:\\Users\\Martinos/nltk_data'
>         - 'C:\\nltk_data'
>         - 'D:\\nltk_data'
>         - 'E:\\nltk_data'
>         - 'E:\\Python26\\nltk_data'
>         - 'E:\\Python26\\lib\\nltk_data'
>         - 'C:\\Users\\Martinos\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
>     **********************************************************************
```

Comment: you can download the pickle model using `>>> nltk.download()`

Answer (score 308):

I had this same problem. Go into a python shell and type:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

Then an installation window appears. Go to the 'Models' tab and select 'punkt' from under the 'Identifier' column. Then click Download and it will install the necessary files. Then it should work!

Comment: Note that in some versions, there is no Models tab and you can go to 'Download' and try to get the package 'punkt' or use any 'list' options to list the available packages.

Comment: it installs into my home folder in a directory nltk_data. Should I copy this directory of punkt into any nltk library folder. pls help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')` should then work and you can use tokenizer like so: `tokenizer.tokenize('The cat. The mat. It Sat.')`. Here nltk tries to resolve the relative path `tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle` against several locations. E.g. on Windows it looks in `%APPDATA%\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt\english.pickle` or `C:\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt\english.pickle` (same for D: and E:). So if you make sure the punkt.zip file is unzipped in such a way that one of those locations exist, it should be able to find it.

Comment: Alternatively, set your `NLTK_DATA` environment variable to point to the nltk_data folder so that `%NLTK_DATA%\tokenizers\punkt\english.pickle` exists.

Comment: If running on a non-X-Window system (like for example over an `ssh` connection) there will be no GUI window and thus no 'Models' tab.

Comment: Python3.5.0, macOS Sierra (10.12.1) - the solution works.

Comment: this works for me. python 3.8, macOS 10.15.7

Answer (score 126):

The main reason why you see that error is nltk couldn't find `punkt` package. Due to the size of `nltk` suite, all available packages are not downloaded by default when one installs it.

You can download `punkt` package like this.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize
```

This is also recommended in the error message in more recent versions:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

If you do not pass any argument to the `download` function, it downloads all packages i.e `chunkers`, `grammars`, `misc`, `sentiment`, `taggers`, `corpora`, `help`, `models`, `stemmers`, `tokenizers`.

```
nltk.download()
```

The above function saves packages to a specific directory. You can find that directory location from comments here. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/67ad86524d42a3a86b1f5983868fd2990b59f1ba/nltk/downloader.py#L1051

Comment: What it does is simply downloading the needed libraries to allow nltk do any tokenization work.

Comment: how to use tokenizers?

Comment: ```python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/my_user/nltk_data...
[nltk_data] Error downloading 'punkt' from
[nltk_data]     <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-
[nltk_data]     pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip>:   HTTP Error
[nltk_data]     503: first byte timeout```

Answer (score 28):

This is what worked for me just now:

```
# Do this in a separate python interpreter session, since you only have to do it once
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

# Do this in your ipython notebook or analysis script
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

sentences = [
    "Mr. Green killed Colonel Mustard in the study with the candlestick. Mr. Green is not a very nice fellow.",
    "Professor Plum has a green plant in his study.",
    "Miss Scarlett watered Professor Plum's green plant while he was away from his office last week."
]

sentences_tokenized = []
for s in sentences:
    sentences_tokenized.append(word_tokenize(s))
```

sentences_tokenized is a list of a list of tokens:

```
[['Mr.', 'Green', 'killed', 'Colonel', 'Mustard', 'in', 'the', 'study', 'with', 'the', 'candlestick', '.', 'Mr.', 'Green', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'very', 'nice', 'fellow', '.'],
['Professor', 'Plum', 'has', 'a', 'green', 'plant', 'in', 'his', 'study', '.'],
['Miss', 'Scarlett', 'watered', 'Professor', 'Plum', "'s", 'green', 'plant', 'while', 'he', 'was', 'away', 'from', 'his', 'office', 'last', 'week', '.']]
```

The sentences were taken from the example [ipython notebook accompanying the book "Mining the Social Web, 2nd Edition"](https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%204%20-%20Mining%20Google%2B.ipynb)

Answer (score 19):

From bash command line, run:

```
$ python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"
```

Comment: I get [nltk_data] Error loading punkt: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.

Comment: @user2478236 GitHub has been blocking the downloader with HTTP 405 due to extremely high volume at times; see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787

Comment: Worked for me, this creates folder `nltk_data` into my home dir and saves punkt into it. I have Fedora 27, Py3.6.

Answer (score 13):

This Works for me:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

In windows you will also get nltk downloader

[image: NLTK Downloader]

Answer (score 11):

Simple `nltk.download()` will not solve this issue. I tried the below and it worked for me:

in the `nltk` folder create a `tokenizers` folder and copy your `punkt` folder into `tokenizers` folder.

This will work.! the folder structure needs to be as shown in the picture![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqY6k.jpg)

Comment: This works for me, in my case I was not able to download via nltk.download...  So I downloaded the file manually from http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/   and create a folder c:/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt and I copied all the files in this location

Answer (score 6):

nltk have its pre-trained tokenizer models. Model is downloading from internally predefined web sources and stored at path of installed nltk package while executing following possible function calls.

E.g. 1
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

E.g. 2
nltk.download('punkt')

If you call above sentence in your code, Make sure you have internet connection without any firewall protections.

I would like to share some more better alter-net way to resolve above issue with more better deep understandings.

Please follow following steps and enjoy english word tokenization using nltk.

Step 1: First download the "english.pickle" model following web path.

Goto link "http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/" and click on "download" at option "107. Punkt Tokenizer Models"

Step 2: Extract the downloaded "punkt.zip" file and find the "english.pickle" file from it and place in C drive.

Step 3: copy paste following code and execute.

```
from nltk.data import load
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer

sentences = [
    "Mr. Green killed Colonel Mustard in the study with the candlestick. Mr. Green is not a very nice fellow.",
    "Professor Plum has a green plant in his study.",
    "Miss Scarlett watered Professor Plum's green plant while he was away from his office last week."
]

tokenizer = load('file:C:/english.pickle')
treebank_word_tokenize = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize

wordToken = []
for sent in sentences:
    subSentToken = []
    for subSent in tokenizer.tokenize(sent):
        subSentToken.extend([token for token in treebank_word_tokenize(subSent)])

    wordToken.append(subSentToken)

for token in wordToken:
    print token
```

Let me know, if you face any problem

Comment: Really nice answer if you are behind a very aggressive firewall.

Answer (score 6):

On Jenkins this can be fixed by adding following like of code to **Virtualenv Builder** under **Build** tab:

`python -m nltk.downloader punkt`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Spyder, go to your active shell and download nltk using below 2 commands.
import nltk
nltk.download()
Then you should see NLTK downloader window open as below, Go to 'Models' tab in this window and click on 'punkt' and download 'punkt'

[image: Window]

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue when using an assigned folder for **multiple** downloads, and I had to append the data path manually:

single download, can be achived as followed (works)

```
import os as _os
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import download as nltk_download

nltk_download('stopwords', download_dir=_os.path.join(get_project_root_path(), 'temp'), raise_on_error=True)

stop_words: list = stopwords.words('english')
```

This code works, meaning that nltk remembers the download path passed in the download fuction. On the other nads if I download a subsequent package I get similar error as described by user:

Multiple downloads raise an error:

```
import os as _os

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from nltk import download as nltk_download

nltk_download(['stopwords', 'punkt'], download_dir=_os.path.join(get_project_root_path(), 'temp'), raise_on_error=True)

print(stopwords.words('english'))
print(word_tokenize("I am trying to find the download path 99."))
```

Error:

Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

import nltk
  nltk.download('punkt')

Now if I append the ntlk data path with my download path, it works:

```
import os as _os

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from nltk import download as nltk_download
from nltk.data import path as nltk_path


nltk_path.append( _os.path.join(get_project_root_path(), 'temp'))


nltk_download(['stopwords', 'punkt'], download_dir=_os.path.join(get_project_root_path(), 'temp'), raise_on_error=True)

print(stopwords.words('english'))
print(word_tokenize("I am trying to find the download path 99."))
```

This works... Not sure why works in one case but not the other, but error message seems to imply that it doesn't check into the download folder the second time.
NB: using windows8.1/python3.7/nltk3.5

Comment: What is `get_project_root_path()`. Where is this function defined?

Comment: Just a function that returns the project root path, you can replace with whatever folder path of yours.

Answer (score 4):

i came across this problem when i was trying to do pos tagging in nltk. 
the way i got it correct is by making a new directory along with corpora directory named "taggers" and copying max_pos_tagger in directory taggers. 

 hope it works for you too. best of luck with it!!!.

Answer (score 2):

In `Python-3.6` I can see the suggestion in the traceback. That's quite helpful.
Hence I will say you guys to pay attention to the error you got, most of the time answers are within that problem ;).

[image]

And then as suggested by other folks here either using python terminal or using a command like `python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('wordnet')"` we can install them on the fly.
You just need to run that command once and then it will save the data locally in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to go to python console and type->

```
import nltk
```

press enter and retype->

```
nltk.download()
```

and then a interface will come. Just search for download button and press it. It will install all the required items and will take time. Give the time and just try it again. Your problem will get solved

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

If all of the above strategies don't work (which is the case for me) just  run the following code:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

I must have wasted hours because of this, and this code seems to have solved my problem.

Reference:

https://www.nltk.org/howto/data.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have all NLTK libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The punkt tokenizers data is quite large at over **35 MB**, this can be a big deal if like me you are running nltk in an environment such as lambda that has limited resources.

If you only need one or perhaps a few language tokenizers you can drastically reduce the size of the data by only including those languages `.pickle` files.

If all you only need to support English then your nltk data size can be reduced to **407 KB** (for the python 3 version).

### Steps

1. Download the nltk punkt data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip
2. Somewhere in your environment create the folders: `nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt`, if using python 3 add another folder `PY3` so that your new directory structure looks like `nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt/PY3`. In my case I created these folders at the root of my project.
3. Extract the zip and move the `.pickle` files for the languages you want to support into the `punkt` folder you just created. **Note: Python 3 users should use the pickles from the `PY3` folder.** With your language files loaded it should look something like: [example-folder-stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sTi.png)
4. Now you just need to add your `nltk_data` folder to the search paths, assuming your data is not in one of the [pre-defined search paths](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L83). You can add your data using either the environment variable `NLTK_DATA='path/to/your/nltk_data'`. You can also add a custom path at runtime in python by doing:

```py
from nltk import data
data.path += ['/path/to/your/nltk_data']
```

**NOTE: If you don't need to load in the data at runtime or bundle the data with your code, it would be best to create your `nltk_data` folders at the [built-in locations that nltk looks for](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L83).**

Answer (score 0):

`nltk.download()` will not solve this issue. I tried the below and it worked for me:

in the `'...AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\tokenizers'` folder, extract downloaded `punkt.zip` folder at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Simply add two lines which is given below:-

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```