# Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found

Tags: python, unix, nltk

My Code:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

ERROR Message:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-31 sentiment]$ python mapper_local_v1.0.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mapper_local_v1.0.py", line 16, in <module>

    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 774, in load

    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 888, in _open

    return find(path_, path + ['']).open()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 618, in find

    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)

LookupError:

Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

    >>>nltk.download()

Searched in:
- '/home/ec2-user/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
- u''
```

I'm trying to run this program in Unix machine:

As per the error message, I logged into python shell from my unix machine then I used the below commands:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

and then I downloaded all the available things using d- down loader and l- list options but still the problem persists.

I tried my best to find the solution in internet but I got the same solution what I did as I mentioned in my above steps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

### once the NLTK Downloader starts

### d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit

Downloader> d

Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> punkt

Answer (score 196):

To add to [alvas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570944/resource-utokenizers-punkt-english-pickle-not-found/26578793#26578793), you can download only the `punkt` corpus:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Downloading `all` sounds like overkill to me. Unless that's what you want.

Comment: I had to upgrade to Latest nltk version 3.2.5 to make nltk.download('punkt') work.

Comment: This is what I get after I run the code above:
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection  
[nltk_data]     refused>

Comment: Regarding my previous issue, all I had to do was to turn off my VPN.

Answer (score 72):

If you're looking to only download the `punkt` model:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

If you're unsure which data/model you need, you can install the **popular** datasets, models and taggers from NLTK:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('popular')
```

With the above command, there is no need to use the GUI to download the datasets.

Answer (score 34):

From the shell you can execute:

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader punkt
```

If you want to install the popular NLTK corpora/models:

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader popular
```

If you want to install *all* NLTK corpora/models:

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader all
```

To list the resources you have downloaded:

```
python -c 'import os; import nltk; print os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora"))'
python -c 'import os; import nltk; print os.listdir(nltk.data.find("tokenizers"))'
```

Answer (score 15):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Open the Python prompt and run the above statements.

The ***sent_tokenize*** function uses an instance of ***PunktSentenceTokenizer*** from the
***nltk.tokenize.punkt*** module. This instance has already been trained and works well for
many European languages. So it knows what punctuation and characters mark the end of a
sentence and the beginning of a new sentence.

Answer (score 10):

The same thing happened to me recently, you just need to download the "punkt" package and it should work.

When you execute "list" (l) after having "downloaded all the available things", is everything marked like the following line?:

```
[*] punkt............... Punkt Tokenizer Models
```

If you see this line with the star, it means you have it, and nltk should be able to load it.

Comment: Hey @supreeth-meka, I am glad you found the solution, it is what I suggested you, can you mark my answer as "Accepted" please?

Answer (score 7):

Go to python console by typing

> $ python

in your terminal. Then, type the following 2 commands in your python shell to install the respective packages:

> >> nltk.download('punkt')
>   >> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting an error despite importing the following,

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

but for google colab this solved my issue.

```
   !python3 -c "import nltk; nltk.download('all')"
```

Answer (score 6):

After adding this line of code, the issue will be fixed:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that I called `nltk.download('all')` as the root user, but the process that eventually used nltk was another user who didn't have access to /root/nltk_data where the content was downloaded.

So I simply recursively copied everything from the download location to one of the paths where NLTK was looking to find it like this:

```
cp -R /root/nltk_data/ /home/ubuntu/nltk_data
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple nltk.download() will not solve this issue. I tried the below and it worked for me:

in the nltk folder create a tokenizers folder and copy your punkt folder into tokenizers folder.

This will work.!
[the folder structure needs to be as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzNtg.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

For me nothing of the above worked, so I just downloaded all the files by hand from the web site http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ and I put them also by hand in a file "tokenizers" inside of "nltk_data" folder. Not a pretty solution but still a solution.

Answer (score 4):

1. Execute the following code:

   ```
   import nltk
   nltk.download()
   ```
2. After this, NLTK downloader will pop out.
3. Select All packages.
4. Download punkt.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rearrange your folders
Move your `tokenizers` folder into `nltk_data` folder.
This doesn't work if you have `nltk_data` folder containing `corpora` folder containing  `tokenizers` folder

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you are using `Jupyter` Notebook and in a notebook, do the following:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

Then one popup window will appear (showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml) 
From that you have to download everything.

Then rerun your code.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. After downloading everything, still 'punkt' error was there. I searched package on my windows machine at C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\tokenizers and I can see 'punkt.zip' present there. I realized that somehow the zip has not been extracted into C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\tokenizers\punk.
Once I extracted the zip, it worked like music.

Answer (score 2):

For me it got solved by using "nltk:"

http://www.nltk.org/howto/data.html

[Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)

```
sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines into your script. This will automatically download the punkt data.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this command does not work:

```py
    import nltk
    nltk.download()
```

but I still have a solution to this problem, it worked for me though.

You have to manually download the punkt file yourself but while writing this the site is not working. You can download it from the archive.org:

https://web.archive.org/web/20230206063107/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip

After downloading the file you have to go to

```
C:\Users\LEMOVO\AppData\Roaming\
```

If the `nltk_data` folder does not exist then create one and go inside the folder. Then create another folder named `tokenizers` and extract the punkt.zip file inside the `tokenizers` folder.

I hope this helps.