# resource not found python textblob Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found

Tags: python, ajax, textblob

The link below shows a similar issue except that his was solved downloading the packages and I already downloaded the packages...
[Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570944/resource-utokenizers-punkt-english-pickle-not-found)

But The weird thing is that I am able to run this on the terminal with no errors, but I have a js file doing a ajax call to this .py file and when it tries to execute it. It returns that error.. but Im not sure why

```
Errors more 
Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
    use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
    nltk.download()
    Searched in:
    - '/var/www/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - u'



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/CSCE-470-Anime-Recommender/py/app.py", line 40, in &lt;module&gt;
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(Functions.classify(UserData))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.train_features = [(self.extract_features(d), c) for d, c in self.train_set]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 169, in extract_features
    return self.feature_extractor(text, self.train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 81, in basic_extractor
    word_features = _get_words_from_dataset(train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 63, in _get_words_from_dataset
    return set(all_words)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 62, in &lt;genexpr&gt;
    all_words = chain.from_iterable(tokenize(words) for words, _ in dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 59, in tokenize
    return word_tokenize(words, include_punc=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/tokenizers.py", line 72, in word_tokenize
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(text))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/base.py", line 64, in itokenize
    return (t for t in self.tokenize(text, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/decorators.py", line 38, in decorated
    raise MissingCorpusError()
MissingCorpusError: 
Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

    python -m textblob.download_corpora

or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data: http://nltk.org/data.html
If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the files into one of the directory's stated and had to change the permissions on one of the files I was including.