# LookupError: Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, lookup, tokenize

I am using pycharm IDE. I dowloaded nltk using file-> settings-> Project Interpreter -> nltk. 
After running my code below I have received an Lookup error

## My code

```html
# My Code
def get_tags(s):
    tuples = pos_tag(word_tokenize(s))
    return [y for x, y in tuples]
    
s = 'She does look like you. Stay the way you are.'
get_tags(s)
```

## Look up error

```
> LookupError: 
> **********************************************************************   Resource punkt not found.   Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain
> the resource:    import nltk
>   >>> nltk.download('punkt')
>      For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html   Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle   Searched in:
>     - 'C:\\Users\\VW3ZTWS/nltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\Users\\VW3ZTWS\\PycharmProjects\\Data_Collection_and_learnings\\venv\\nltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\Users\\VW3ZTWS\\PycharmProjects\\Data_Collection_and_learnings\\venv\\share\\nltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\Users\\VW3ZTWS\\PycharmProjects\\Data_Collection_and_learnings\\venv\\lib\\nltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\Users\\VW3ZTWS\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
>     - 'C:\\nltk_data'
>     - 'D:\\nltk_data'
>     - 'E:\\nltk_data'
>     - ''
> **********************************************************************
```

## What i tried

I googled and follow the info from [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750608/error-installing-nltk-supporting-packages-nltk-download) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570944/resource-utokenizers-punkt-english-pickle-not-found). But none solved my problem. 
Even i tried manually by downloading the Punkt tokenizer model from [Link3](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) and save it in tokenizers folder with unzipped files and tried to run my code. But still it does not work.

**Kindly support to solve this issue**

[image]

[image]

## comments reference picture

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just do this in the code `import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')` without the GUI.

Comment: When i do that this is what I get...
``import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 11001]
[nltk_data]     getaddrinfo failed>
Out[34]: 
False
``

Comment: Also, I have tried downloader directly, but some error splits out, please see the picture in the question now , i had edited....

Comment: Does your machine have access to internet?

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Could you try this on your command line before the Python interpreter? `pip install -U pip` and then `pip install -U nltk`. Then inside Python `import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: What is the output when you run the instructions in my last comment?

Comment: please refer to the picture added in the question.I tried the following in cmd
1)pip install nltk
2)pip install -U pip
3) pip install -U nltk

Comment: After that, could you do `python -m nltk.downloader popular`? Then try to use punkt again, it should work.

Comment: Still i cannot able to download it, even after using the command.
please refer to the picture in my question @alvas