# Docker NLTK Download

Tags: python, docker, nltk

I am building a docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip

ADD . /app

RUN apt-get install -y python-scipy

RUN pip install -r /arrc/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /app

CMD python app.py
```

Everything goes well until I run the image and get the following error:

```
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - u''
**********************************************************************
```

I have had this problem before and it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load) however I am not sure how to approach it using Docker. I have tried:

```
CMD python
CMD import nltk
CMD nltk.download()
```

as well as:

```
CMD python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data popular
```

But am still getting the error.

Comment: this is wrong "CMD python
CMD import nltk
CMD nltk.download()" it is the same as  open a terminal, type `python`, open another terminal, type `import nltk` and so (of course the second command will fail, as it is not in Python

Comment: maybe `RUN python -c 'import nltk ; nltk.download()'` or something like that (I am not sure of the syntax)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, try adding instead:

> `RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt`

This will run the command and install the requested files to `//nltk_data/`

The problem is most likely related to using CMD vs. RUN in the Dockerfile. Documentation for CMD:

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

which is used during `docker run <image>`, not during build. So other CMD lines probably were overwritten by the last `CMD python app.py` line.

Comment: do you know if I just COPY the nltk_data folder, do I need to copy both uncompressed folders and zip files or only zipfiles?

Comment: I am using this approach but I am getting this error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour

Comment: Here's more info from NLTK to pair with the command above. https://www.nltk.org/data.html#command-line-installation

Comment: I also got the warning when building the docker container so I instead used 

`RUN python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"`

which builds without warning

Answer (score 13):

well I tried all the methods suggested but nothing worked so I realized that nltk module searched in /root/nltk_data

step 1: i downloaded the punkt on my machine
by using

```
python3
>>import nltk
>>nltk.download('punkt')
```

And the punkt was in /root/nltk_data/tokenizer

step 2: i copied tokenizer folder to my director
and my directory looked something like this

```
.
|-app/
|-tokenizers/
|--punkt/
|---all those pkl files
|--punkt.zip
```

and
step 3: then i modified the Dockerfile which copied that to my docker instance

```
COPY ./tokenizers /root/nltk_data/tokenizers
```

step 4: The new instance had punkt

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. It was the simplest solution to the problem and the only one that worked for me. My Docker:

```COPY ./nltk_data /usr/local/nltk_data```

Answer (score 5):

I got this to work for google cloud build by indicating a download destination within the container.

`RUN [ "python3", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')" ]`

Full Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

# install requirements
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirements.txt

RUN [ "python3", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='/usr/local/nltk_data')" ]

CMD exec uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT main:app
```

Comment: Just Curious... What does the "-c" part of the RUN command do?

Comment: command - it runs python code inline, the code that you would normally write in a file and then execute with 'python file_name.py'.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue when I was creating docker image with ubuntu image and python3 for django application.

I resolved as shown below.

```
# start from an official image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev python3-virtualenv

# arbitrary location choice: you can change the directory
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src

# copy our project code
COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src

# install dependency for running service
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m nltk.downloader punkt
RUN python3 -m nltk.downloader wordnet

# Setup supervisord
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Start processes
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I had to do this: see `RUN cp -r /root/nltk_data /usr/local/share/nltk_data`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    python3 \
    build-essential \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

ADD requirements.txt .
# in requirements.txt: pandas, numpy, wordcloud, matplotlib, nltk, sklearn

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
RUN [ "python3", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('stopwords')" ]
RUN [ "python3", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')" ]
RUN cp -r /root/nltk_data /usr/local/share/nltk_data 

RUN addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app app

WORKDIR /home/app
ADD inputfile .
ADD script.py . 
# the script uses the python modules: pandas, numpy, wordcloud, matplotlib, nltk, sklearn

RUN chown app:app -R /home/app
USER app
RUN python3 script.py inputfile outputfile
```