# Python NLTK error: english.pickle resource in NLTK not found

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

Trying to learn NLP and Sentiment Analysis in Python and came across the NLTK. Did a few tutorials but got stuck on the tokenization function as it does not work on me (command line is saying that I don't have the resources).

I already tried installing `punkt` and although that was downloaded, the command line still presents the same error:

```
Resource u'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle'
not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the
resource:  >>> nltk.download()
Searched in:
  - 'C:\\Users\\JeromePogi/nltk_data'
  - 'C:\\nltk_data'
  - 'D:\\nltk_data'
  - 'E:\\nltk_data'
  - 'C:\\Python27\\nltk_data'
  - 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\nltk_data'
  - 'C:\\Users\\JeromePogi\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
  - u''
```

I've literally tried everything including putting the nltk_data folder in each of the directories that it has searched in but to no avail. What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)

Comment: `import nltk; nltk.download('all')`

Comment: Not a duplicate, it is missing a different resource. @Alvas, it's enough to recommend `nltk.download('book')` as a catch-all if you don't know the specific resource that is missing. (Or to avoid similar problems in the future.)

Comment: I like the "batteries-included" solutions =)

Comment: `download('book')` includes enough batteries to last most users forever.

Comment: @JermoeIbanez, would you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved? This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 6):

try installing "maxent_treebank_pos_tagger" using nltk.download() in the python console

Comment: The possible duplicate (which is from 3-4 years ago) suggests `nltk.download('punkt')` - what is the difference?

Comment: The `punkt` tokenizer model is used to break up plain text into sentences, and is used when the NLTK reads plain text corpora.  For POS tagging, you need the maxent tagger's model.

Answer (score 4):

From the shell/terminal/cmd, you can use:

```
python -m nltk.downloader maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
```

(might need to be sudo on Linux)

It will install `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger` (i.e. the standard treebank POS tagger in NLTK) and fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I didn't properly realise, how to pass language as a parameter. My code was:

```
word_tokenize('So was he doing.', 'en')
```

Which is WRONG. **Use full language names**.