# NLTK Lookup Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

While running a Python script using NLTK I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpicklesave.py", line 56, in <module>
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 110, in pos_tag
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py", line 140, in __init__
    AP_MODEL_LOC = str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 641, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptro
  n_tagger.pickle' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to
  obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Can anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use

```
>>> nltk.download()
```

to install the missing module (the *Perceptron Tagger*).

(check also the answers to [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load))

Comment: nltk.download starts a large download of data: all, all-corpora, all-nltk, book, popular,test, and thirdparty

Answer (score 48):

First answer said the missing module is 'the Perceptron Tagger', actually its name in nltk.download is 'averaged_perceptron_tagger'

You can use this to fix the error

`nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')`

Comment: it is `python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger` if you want to download it from the command line

Answer (score 30):

**TL;DR**

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```

Or to download all packages + data + docs:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

See [How do I download NLTK data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data)

Comment: Hi, may I know where this content will be saved after downloading all the nltk data by using `nltk.download("all
")`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data and more specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383314/610569

Comment: Hi, Its just downloads all the packages and stops...rest codes don't execute

Answer (score 15):

**Install all nltk resources in one line:**

```
python3 -c "import nltk; nltk.download('all')"
```

the data will be saved at `~/nltk_data`

---

**Install only specific resource:**

Substitute "all" for "averaged_perceptron_tagger" to install only this module.

```
python3 -c "import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')"
```

Comment: nltk.download(), this is working fine. already marked as correct answer.

Comment: @ShivShankar you need to do `python3` then `import nltk`, `nltk.download()` which will put you on a download prompt asking the package name that you want to download. It is not a wrong solution, it's just not as simple as the one I'm proposing.

Comment: for folks using google colab, the following version of Lucas Azevedo's answer worked for me 
    import nltk; nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

Answer (score 2):

Problem:
Lookup error when extracting count vectorizer from scikit learn. Below is code snippet.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process).fit(X)
```

Solution:
Try to run the below code and then try to install the stopwords from corpora natural language processing toolkit!!

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download NLTK missing module just by

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

This will shows the NLTK download screen. 
If it shows SSL Certificate verify failed error. Then it should works by disabling SSL check with below code!

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! if I missed other editor but this is working fine in **Google Colab**

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even by writing
`nltk.download('module_name')`, it does not get downloaded. At those times, you can open python in interactive mode and then download by using `nltk.download('module_name')`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download that module for nltk.
The better way is to open a python command line and type

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

That's all.

Comment: This solution is already provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73488002/2847330). If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.

Comment: will you tell me where you are running your code?

Answer (score 0):

if you have already executed `python -m textblob.download_corpora` if not first run `import nltk nltk.downlod('all')` or `nltk.downlod('all-corpora')`
and if issue remains there then it might be because some packages are not being unzipp.
in my case have to unzip wordnet as my error was
`Resource wordnet not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:`
solution`cd /home/app/nltk_data/corpora` then `unzip wordnet.zip`

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3028

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code, and it works for me:

```
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type `python` and enter
3. Type `import ntlk` and enter
4. Type `nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')` and enter

It should fix your error.

Answer (score -1):

If you have not downloaded ntlk then firstly download ntlk and then use this `nltk.download('punkt')` it will give you the result.

Comment: I don't believe the punkt tokenizer is the missing piece here. See, for example, Lucas' answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import nltk


nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
```

Use this this might work