# nltk doesn't add $NLTK_DATA to search path?

Tags: python, environment-variables, nltk, search-path

under linux,I have set env var $NLTK_DATA('/home/user/data/nltk'),and blew test works as expected

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.words()
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', ...]
```

but when running another python script,I got:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
nltk.download()
Searched in:
- '/home/user/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
- u''
```

---

As we can see,nltk doesn't add $NLTK_DATA to search path,after appending NLTK_DATA dir manually:

```
nltk.data.path.append("/NLTK_DATA_DIR");
```

script runs as expected,question is:

How to make nltk to add $NLTK_DATA to it's search path automatically?

Comment: Since the `nltk_data` directory is static, why do you need to find the path automatically?

Comment: By default NLTK is automatically finds the `nltk_data` directory in these directory, - '/home/user/nltk_data'
 '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data',  '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'

Comment: I have specified nltk.download() to download data to $NLTK_DATA,if don't add $NLTK_DATA to search directory,it seems that the downloaded data can't be used by scripts(but simple command  can't used).

Comment: As long as `nltk.path.append()` is in your script, you don't really need to worry about the data directory in `os.environ`. See updated answer.

Comment: The nltk does add the paths from `NLTK_DATA` to the data search path. The problem must be caused by something else: The second python script does not inherit the environment? The path is incorrect (or possibly a relative path, which only works in some directories)? Who knows. But the solution (for anyone having the same issue) is to examine and fix the setting of the variable. The NLTK Does The Right Thing when it sees the variable.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to set the $NLTK_DATA before running your scripts, you can do it within the python scripts with:

```
import nltk
nltk.path.append('/home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data/')
```

E.g. let's move the the `nltk_data` to a non-standard path that NLTK won't find it automatically:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
chunkers  corpora  grammars  help  misc  models  stemmers  taggers  tokenizers
alvas@ubi:~$ mkdir some_path
alvas@ubi:~$ mv nltk_data/ some_path/
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
ls: cannot access nltk_data/: No such file or directory
alvas@ubi:~$ ls some_path/nltk_data/
chunkers  corpora  grammars  help  misc  models  stemmers  taggers  tokenizers
```

Now, we use the `nltk.path.append()` hack:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
>>> import os
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.path.append('/home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data/')
>>> nltk.pos_tag('this is a foo bar'.split())
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'JJ'), ('bar', 'NN')]
>>> nltk.data
<module 'nltk.data' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.pyc'>
>>> nltk.data.path
['/home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data/', '/home/alvas/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
>>> exit()
```

Let's move it back and see whether it works:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data
ls: cannot access nltk_data: No such file or directory
alvas@ubi:~$ mv some_path/nltk_data/ .
alvas@ubi:~$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.data.path
['/home/alvas/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
>>> nltk.pos_tag('this is a foo bar'.split())
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'JJ'), ('bar', 'NN')]
```

---

If you really really want to find nltk_data automagically, use something like:

```
import scandir
import os, sys
import time

import nltk

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in scandir.walk(path):
        if root.endswith(name):
            return root

def find_nltk_data():
    start = time.time()
    path_to_nltk_data = find('nltk_data', '/')
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Finding nltk_data took', time.time() - start
    print >> sys.stderr,  'nltk_data at', path_to_nltk_data
    with open('where_is_nltk_data.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(path_to_nltk_data)
    return path_to_nltk_data

def magically_find_nltk_data():
    if os.path.exists('where_is_nltk_data.txt'):
        with open('where_is_nltk_data.txt') as fin:
            path_to_nltk_data = fin.read().strip()
        if os.path.exists(path_to_nltk_data):
            nltk.data.path.append(path_to_nltk_data)
        else:
            nltk.data.path.append(find_nltk_data())
    else:
        path_to_nltk_data  = find_nltk_data()
        nltk.data.path.append(path_to_nltk_data)


magically_find_nltk_data()
print nltk.pos_tag('this is a foo bar'.split())
```

Let's call that python script, `test.py`:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
chunkers  corpora  grammars  help  misc  models  stemmers  taggers  tokenizers
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
Finding nltk_data took 4.27330780029
nltk_data at /home/alvas/nltk_data
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'JJ'), ('bar', 'NN')]
alvas@ubi:~$ mv nltk_data/ some_path/
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
Finding nltk_data took 4.75850391388
nltk_data at /home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'JJ'), ('bar', 'NN')]
```

Comment: is there any one-stop way to solve this problem like adding  a system variable?

Comment: Appending the data paths with: `nltk.path.append('/home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data/')` after `import nltk` should work, it's just that sometimes the user don't know where the NLTK directory is, then you would need to use `magically_find_nltk_data()`

Comment: Maybe I haven't express question clearly enough.I have set an env var NLTK_DATA to a dir,and hope nltk.download() will add this dir to search path automatically and search this dir to decide whether a content has been downloaded ,and if not,download new content to this dir,but nltk.download() doesn't.Question is how to let nltk recognize env var NLTK_DATA

Comment: On the terminal do: `export NLTK_DATA=/home/alvas/some_path/nltk_data/` before calling your python script?

Comment: I am trying in windows below error got while nltk.path.append('<my nltk_data path>')AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'path'

Comment: Did you name your file/script as `nltk.py`? If so change the name and try again.

Comment: @JON the correct syntax is `nltk.data.path.append` as indicated in the original question

Answer (score 0):

If you are someone who wants to install the NLTK data in a conda environment, and doesn't want to specify the data location in every script, or export the environment variable, you need to do the following:

1. Activate your desired conda environment.
2. Print `sys.prefix` within your conda environment, and copy this path (let's say `/home/dickens/envs/nltk_env`.
3. Run `nltk.download()` within the conda environment, select your desired packages, and append `/share/nltk_data` to your path from above as the download location. For e.g. in our case, it will become `/home/dickens/envs/nltk_env/share/nltk_data`.
4. You are now good to go!

Answer (score 0):

It will not. by default nltk search for data in corpora folder.
You must create corpora folder then put your nltk data into it.
I had the same problem, somehow I downloaded nltk data it did the same.
after that add nltk.data.path = data_dir with solve issue.

[My Folder structure for this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/470RQ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).