# How to remove nltk from python and from my system and also from command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, nltk, nltk-trainer

I tried downloading nltk by using the command on the python command prompt

```
import nltk
nltk.download() //after this it started downloading
```

Now I want to delete all the nltk files from my system, please help in uninstalling and removing all the files of nltk.

Comment: just find the directory in which they were installed and delete it.

Comment: they were downloaded in C folder and i have deleted but how do i know that all its files are removed permanently?

Comment: How did you install `nltk`? If you're using `pip` then try `pip uninstall nltk`.

Comment: i installed nltk by writing the commands in the command promt import nltk nltk.download()

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/36383314/610569 to find the path where nltk saves the data. And then just delete the directory. BTW `nltk-trainer` and `nltk` are 2 different libraries =)

Comment: @alvas nice tip

Answer (score 2):

**Linux -**

Open up a terminal and type `sudo pip uninstall nltk`

**Windows -**

To uninstall NLTK 3:

Open the directory `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages`

Delete: `nltk` and `nltk-3.0...egg-info`

**Refer -**

[How to remove an data/models from nltk dowloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113266/how-to-remove-an-data-models-from-nltk-dowloader)

[How to uninstall a package installed with pip install --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user)

[Na-Rae Han's Python/NLTK FAQ](https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/faq.html)