# How to remove an data/models from nltk dowloader?

Tags: python, directory, nltk, delete-file

I installed some NLTK-packages in python3 NLTK (via `nltk.download()`), tried them and -not needing them- want to remove them now.

How can I remove for example the package `large_grammars` from my NLTK-installation? (I do not want to remove the complete NLTK-installation!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default NLTK packages/data are saved in the `nltk_data` directory.

First, you have to find where the directory might be:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.data.path
['/home/alvas/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

Check the exact location of `nltk_data`:

```
>>> import os
>>> next(p for p in nltk.data.path if os.path.exists(p))
'/home/alvas/nltk_data'
```

On linux, simply go to the directory on the command line:

```
$ cd /home/alvas/nltk_data/
$ ls
corpora  grammars  tokenizers
$ cd grammars/
$ ls
large_grammars  large_grammars.zip
$ rm -rf large_grammars 
$ rm large_grammars.zip
```

Comment: in your code you missed to `import os` (before checking the "exact location"). worked! thank you! (I thought I would need to remove it inside the nltk-framework.)