# HTTP Error 403 Forbidden - when downloading nltk data

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am facing some problem for accessing `nltk data`. I have tried `nltk.download()`. The gui page has come with `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error. I have also try to install from command line which is provided [here](http://www.nltk.org/data.html).

```
python -m nltk.downloader all
```

and get this error.

> > C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour warn(RuntimeWarning(msg)) [nltk_data] Error loading all: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

I also go through [How do I download NLTK data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data) and [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from the nltk download server. If you look at the gui's config, it's pointing to this link

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
```

If you access this link in the browser, you get this as a message :

```
Error 403 Forbidden.

Forbidden.

Guru Mediation:

Details: cache-lcy1125-LCY 1501134862 2002107460

Varnish cache server
```

So, I was going to file an issue on github, but someone else already did that here : https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1791

A workaround was suggested here: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787.

Based on the discussion on github:

> It seems like the Github is down/blocking access to the raw content on
>   the repo.

The suggested workaround is to manually download as follows:

```
PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA=/home/username/nltk_data/
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

People also suggested using an laternative index as follows:

```
python -m nltk.downloader -u https://pastebin.com/raw/D3TBY4Mj punkt
```

Comment: I download the data form https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip manually and put into a directory with extracting. Basically which data is need for me and worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /nltk/downloader.py

And change the default url:

DEFAULT_URL = 'http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/index.xml'

to

DEFAULT_URL = 'http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/'

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is:

```
PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA=/home/username/nltk_data/
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

[link](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1338)

Alternative solution is not working for me

```
python -m nltk.downloader -u https://pastebin.com/raw/D3TBY4Mj punkt
```