# Issues while downloading on pydroid

Tags: pydroid

```py
import seaborn as sns 

sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

```py
import nltk 
nltk.download("wordnet")
```

```
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [Errno 110]
[nltk_data]     Connection timed out>
```

I am getting these issues on pydroid for android.
I am on personal mobile data.
I cannot check on PC as that is not available.
I have searched Google and stackoverflow.com. But nothing fits my situation.
Kindly redirect me to link on stackoverflow.com where it matches or share workaround on pydroid if known!

I have tried installing inbuilt libraries within pydroid.
IIEC has permissions/repository plug in.
I have installed those too.

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Oct  6 2021, 01:34:26) [GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

Inbuilt interpreter screenshot.
This fails too.

```py
import urllib.request 

request_url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/') 

if request_url.read() :
    print("works! ")
```

```
works!

[Program finished]
```

Trying to check if Internet permission is OK

Comment: Have you tried checking firewall/proxy that might blocking communication?

Comment: My mobile is personal mobile and hence doesn't use proxy to access Internet.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os as _os

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from nltk import download as nltk_download
from nltk.data import path as nltk_path


nltk_path.append( _os.path.join('/storage/emulated/0/Machine Learning 2', 'temp'))


nltk_download(['stopwords', 'punkt'], download_dir=_os.path.join('/storage/emulated/0/Machine Learning 2', 'temp'), raise_on_error=True)

print(stopwords.words('english'))
print(word_tokenize("I am trying to find the download path 99."))
```

I installed pydroid on my mobile and recreated the issue.
This worked for me.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)

Comment: `import seaborn as sns` `iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')` `print(iris.head())`
This has started working somehow! Any possible explanation?

Comment: It has stopped working again

Comment: Then the issue is definitely at ISP. Try some VPN to filter traffic.